# Format XML DateTime as %d/%/m%Y

Tags: r, xml

I'm processing orders from a customer whom only provides their order file as a pdf or xml downloaded file. I'm using R Version 2023.03.0+386 (2023.03.0+386) on macos with the (XML) package and running the below line of code:

The source xml data looks like below:

```
            <OrderDate>
                <DateTime>
                    <Year>2023</Year>
                    <Month>03</Month>
                    <Day>20</Day>
                    <Hour>00</Hour>
                    <Minute>00</Minute>
                    <Second>00</Second>
                    <TimeZone>+10:00</TimeZone>
                </DateTime>
            </OrderDate>
```

So I tried:

```
orderdate<-getNodeSet(wwxml,"//PurchaseOrderDetail//POHeader//OrderDate//DateTime")%>%lapply(xmlValue)
```

I successfully extracted the value "20230320000000+10:00". How do I format this as a date showing only dd/mm/yyyy? After extracting this value, I created a function and piped it to the end of the getNodeSet command:

```
dateclean<-function(x)format(as_date(str_extract(x,"^\\d{8}")), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
orderdate<-getNodeSet(wwxml,"//PurchaseOrderDetail//POHeader//OrderDate//DateTime")%>%lapply(xmlValue)%>%lapply(dateclean(.)
print(orderdate) "20/03/2023"
```

I am trying to understand whether I have got lucky with a 'hack' approach, or can I expect to reliably extract a correct date using the above, regardless of the actual date value? It feels like a lucky result, and I am open to suggestions for a more elegant and/or trustworthy code.

Comment: I'm thinking there must be a way to only read the <Year><Month><Day> child nodes?

Comment: XML processing is not my core skill, but something like `sapply(getNodeSet(xp, "//OrderDate/DateTime/*[self::Year|self::Month|self::Day]"), xmlValue)` maybe?

Comment: @thelatemail appreciate the tip mate! I used your suggestion, with a couple of tweaks to keep it in line with my object setting.